# What are your best practices for working with test data in Django?

Tags: python, django, testing, tdd

I currently use a single fixtures file per application, but as projects grow, the tests are taking far too long and I believe that the (now large) fixtures being loaded for each test class are at fault.

I've avoided having lots of smaller fixtures because of concerns about duplication and maintenance, but I know think that's unavoidable.

Before I go down that path though, I thought I would ask what others do with fixtures for testing their applications/projects.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you have hit on a problem with a large set of fixtures. The constant deserialization/loading does add up as your test suite grows. I would suggest writing utility functions to create data as you need it rather than relying on fixtures. For instance you might have a function to create a new `auth.User` like:

```
def create_user(data=None):
    data = data or {}
    defaults = {
        'username': get_random_string(),
        'email': get_random_email(),
        'password': get_random_string()
    }
    defaults.update(data)
    return User.objects.create_user(**defaults)
```

Writing a function to generate a random string/email is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use sqlite for testing purposes. There's a considerable difference in speed compared to other db engines.

Comment: It's faster because it doesn't validate any of the data that you put in.

Comment: @Mark, your point about data-validation is in most cases irrelevant when working with django. Tests with sqlite is `tremendously` faster because sqlite works in-memory. It is possible to configure django settings so that mysql or postrges would use in-memory tables instead of regular ones, if you do that then there are no significant difference between databases.

Comment: The goal of writing tests isn't to have a fast test suite; it's to make sure your code does what it should when you move it to production where you should not be using Sqlite. It's trivial to write code in Django and subsequent test cases which will pass on Sqlite and fail on a real database. You don't do yourself any favors by using Sqlite for testing.